# Why is my Alto Wine a quest item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got Alto Wine in my inventory that's apparently flagged as a quest item. I can't drop it, and I can't drink it, and every time I pick up another Alto Wine (which I now dread) it adds another 0.5 units of weight I can't get rid of. I even went so far as stealing a bottle of Alto Wine and having the guards confiscate my stolen property to try to get rid of it - no luck.

Is this a bug, or is it actually for a quest? Which quest? I'd like to get rid of this.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with an amethyst. I needed one amethyst for the quest, but I was unable to drop my stack of 9 amethysts.

Comment: as a quest item they donot have weight as i have over 150 of them now lol its good to know what quest they r 4 thow i may do that quest next lol

Comment: Quest Items weighs nothing, I once had 140 of those wine, yet a total inventory weight of below 70.

Comment: I have 22 of the damn things, I cant drop sell or even drink them.

Comment: @pisidon  so all 150 weight nothing or only the one needed for the quest?

Comment: @alexanderpas so all 150 weight nothing or only the one needed for the quest?

Comment: @IAdapter ALL of them, since the quest status is bound to the item ID.

Comment: Oke, it's very important if you accept a quest you look very closely at the top left of your'e screen to see a questgiver puts something in your'e inventory. Remember the name of the item (or a part) and search it in the inventory.
You learn faster where future items are categorized. This way, you don't get too confused. Let me gues this ale quest item.
You stole a bottle of ale in Whiterun for a begger, but got distracted and forgot to deliver the bottle?
At that point, quest is still running and the ale is a quest item :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't apply at all.  That isn't the quest, and you aren't "given" the wine by a questgiver.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this particular bottle of Alto Wine is related to a quest that you will come across in the game.

It's called "A Night To Remember" and can be picked up at any tavern.

Check out this link for more info (If you don't mind spoilers):

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember

Try doing that quest and see if it fixes your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I did the quest and it took ... i guess one of the non-quest bottles. So now I've just got 3 weight units stuck in limbo -_- Ah well.

Comment: Hey, I take that back. It *was* stuck, but at some point the game seems to have reconsidered and let me get rid of them. I'm good now :)